# Clean URLs won't work in Drupal 7 on IIS

Tags: php, drupal, iis, clean-urls

I am using Drupal 7 and IIS 8 as my web server.

When I click *Clean URLs* in the configuration, I check it and then click save, then it loads the page without the box checked. However I can type in the URL alias of page ex: `example.com/?q=user` and `domain.com/user` both go to the same page.

However when it creates the menus and such, the links all contain the `?q=` parameter. I checked the *web.config* and copied the one Drupal said to use, even though they looked identical, but I am lost as to why this won't work. Any insights would be helpful.

Comment: [Here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=clean+urls+iis) is a search on the [Drupal](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/) site that might help. You might receive more attention to this question there, so let me know if you want to migrate it to that site.

Comment: I will attempt these tomorrow and update the question if they work or not. Thank you

Comment: @JayLamay were you able to try those?